# Relevant Distribution

Tags: probability

I have a 7 year data set with revenue, revenue growth percentage, ebitda liabilities and assets.
 I have been asked to find the underlying relevant distribution used in the above data set. I'm drawing a blank everywhere on how to find this.
does anybody have a clue as to how I can get around this? I'm told its either discrete probability distribution or continuous probability distribution

Comment: start with a histogram, guess at some, use the chi square goodness of fit test. If you want a more sophisticated approach, estimate moments with the EM algorithm or learn it with Metropolis Hastings.

Comment: If your two choices are literally discrete or continuous, those are not specific probability distributions, but rather classes of distributions, differentiated by the kinds of values they govern.  Variables that can be enumerated, such as the flip of a coin or the roll of a die, are discrete.  Those that take on essentially any value in a given range, such as the amount of money in my bank account, are continuous.  (Strictly speaking, because money is generally rounded to something like a cent, it's a discrete variable, but it's treated as a continuous variable for expedience.)

Comment: This seems like a good time to point out, incidentally, that just because a variable is random, does not mean that any value is as likely as any other.  Height, for instance, is a continuous random variable, but it's not as likely for a person to be six feet tall as they are to be sixty feet tall; six feet is obviously much more likely.  More prosaically, even within the realm of reality, six feet is more likely than six-foot-five, and this is represented in the specific probability distribution used to model height (typically a normal, or "bell curve," distribution).